# Tallying coincidences of numbers (Part 2) - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Following on from: [Tallying co-incidences of numbers in columns of a matrix - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672922/tallying-co-incidences-of-numbers-in-columns-of-a-matrix-matlab)

I was wondering how best to go about the same task when the data is processed differently. Starting with a matrix of:

```
A = 

201 202
203 204
201 203
201 203
205 201
```

I simply need a matrix that tallies the coincidence of each number from Column 1 to Column 2 i.e.

```
201   202
```

201 occurs with 202 once and so on (it ignores that 202 occurs with 201, removing duplicates). This is stored in a 2D matrix with min(A):max(A) running down both sides.

The desired output for the above example (A) would be:

```
   201 202 203 204 205
201 0   1   2   0   0
202 0   0   0   0   0
203 0   0   0   1   0
204 0   0   0   0   0
205 1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: So what would the desired output be in this example?

Comment: Also, "_it ignores that 2285 occurs with 2275, removing duplicates_" and "_duplicates may occur and so the tally must be able to increment_" seem contradictory. Please explain

Comment: I've edited the OP to include a simpler example and the desired output.

Comment: I want the tallying to occur from Column 1 to Column 2 only. If the reverse pairings are added (like 202-201, 204-203, 203-201, 203-201 and 201-205 from the above example), it will fill the tally with duplicates.

Comment: So, if there were `[202 201]`, shouldn't it fill [Row 2,Col 1] position as 1?

Comment: Yes `[202 201]` will add to 2,1 but it would not add to 1,2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
A1 = A-min(A(:))+1 %// Get offsetted values

Aout = zeros(max(A1(:)))
%// For performance: Aout(max(A1(:)),max(A1(:)))=0; 
%// But for this performance trick to work, make sure Aout isnt defined before.
%// Source - http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance

idx = sub2ind(size(Aout),A1(:,1),A1(:,2))
%// For performance: idx = (A1(:,2)-1)*size(Aout,1) + A1(:,1)

unqidx = unique(idx) %// get unique indices
Aout(unqidx) = histc(idx,unqidx) %// put counts of indices into their places
```

Sample run with an extra added row of input data -

```
>> A
A =
   201   202
   203   204
   201   203
   201   203
   205   201
   202   201
>> Aout
Aout =
     0     1     2     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: This seems spot on. Thank you! I'm curious as to why the second version of `idx` would improve performance?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Glad you asked, I did some benchmarking on that comparing the performance oriented raw version against the MATLAB builtin `sub2ind`. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528685/filter-matrix-rows-depending-on-values-in-a-second-matrix/25530905#25530905) for the benchmark results. In most cases the raw version is around `2x` better than the builtin one and the reason I could guess is that because the raw version avoids the function call overhead and all the error checking that's part of the MATLAB builtins.